# Hidden Markov Model is not accurate with me

Tags: machine-learning, python, machine-learning-model, speech-to-text, markov-hidden-model

I am new to Speech Recognition and want to implement a simple words classifier that predicts the spoken word is one of the 100 words I have in my system. So I have a dataset of audios with every folder being a word and has around 100 audios for this word.
Now I followed some tutorials to use HMM and GMM for that
so I have two functions one to train the model and save it locally and the other one to use the model that is saved locally to predict the spoken word. My problem is that the function that predicts the words does not predict right. Can anyone look into my code and help me figure out how to improve it to predict accurately?

````
def train_model(data_path="dataset", n_components=3, n_mfcc=13, model_file="hmm_models.joblib"):
    """
    Train an HMM model for each word in the training data and save them to a file.

    Parameters:
    data_path (str): Path to the directory containing the training data.
    n_components (int): Number of states in each HMM model.
    n_mfcc (int): Number of MFCC coefficients to extract from each audio file.
    model_file (str): Path to the file where the trained models will be saved.

    Returns:
    None
    """

    # Load the audio files and extract features
    word_folders = [os.path.join(data_path, folder) for folder in os.listdir(data_path) if not folder.startswith('.') and os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_path, folder))]
    data = []
    for folder in word_folders:
        audio_files = [os.path.join(folder, file) for file in os.listdir(folder) if not file.startswith('.')]
        mfccs = []
        for file in audio_files:
            y, sr = librosa.load(file, sr=None)
            mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y, sr=sr, n_mfcc=n_mfcc)
            mfccs.append(mfcc.T)
        data.append(np.concatenate(mfccs))

    # Create the HMM models
    models = []
    for i in range(len(data)):
        model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=n_components, covariance_type="diag")
        model.fit(data[i], lengths=[len(data[i])])
        models.append(model)

    # Save the trained models to a file
    dump(models, model_file)


def predict_word(audio_file_path, model_file="hmm_models.joblib", n_mfcc=13, data_path="dataset"):
    models = load(model_file)
    y_test, sr_test = librosa.load(audio_file_path, sr=None)
    mfcc_test = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=y_test, sr=sr_test, n_mfcc=n_mfcc)
    log_likelihoods = []
    for model in models:
        log_likelihood, state_sequence = model.score_samples(mfcc_test.T)
        log_likelihoods.append(log_likelihood)
    words = []
    word_folders = [os.path.join(data_path, folder) for folder in os.listdir(data_path) if
                    not folder.startswith('.') and os.path.isdir(os.path.join(data_path, folder))]
    for folder in word_folders:
        words.append(os.path.basename(folder))
    predicted_word = words[np.argmax(log_likelihoods)]
    return predicted_word


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Train the model and save it to a file
    train_model(data_path="dataset", n_components=3, n_mfcc=13, model_file="hmm_models.joblib")

    # Predict the word corresponding to a test audio file
    print(predict_word(audio_file_path="test1.wav", model_file="hmm_models.joblib", n_mfcc=13))
    print(predict_word(audio_file_path="test2.wav", model_file="hmm_models.joblib", n_mfcc=13))
    print(predict_word(audio_file_path="test3.wav", model_file="hmm_models.joblib", n_mfcc=13))
```
````